# What are the default assembly loaded in PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell

I can't find anywhere about the default assembly loaded in the PowerShell 7.
As I need to make use of some .NET Core libraries directly in the PowerShell 7 Script, so it'll be helpful if I can tell which assemblies are already loaded.

Comment: There is no formal contract that specifies what is and isn't loaded, so your best approach would remain to load the assemblies explicitly, and not rely on whatever the current version happens to do. At worst the load will be redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate the assemblies currently loaded by calling `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |ForEach-Object GetName |Sort-Object Name
```

Run in a fresh instance of `pwsh` to see what's available out of the gate.

As [mklement0 notes in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072627/what-are-the-default-assembly-loaded-in-powershell-7/69073141?noredirect=1#comment122083954_69073141), you'll want to launch `pwsh` with the `-NoProfile` command line switch to avoid listing explicit dependencies of modules or assemblies loaded in your profile script (here using an encoded version of the one-liner above, for portability):

```
pwsh.exe -NoProfile -EncodedCommand WwBTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQAuAEEAcABwAEQAbwBtAGEAaQBuAF0AOgA6AEMAdQByAHIAZQBuAHQARABvAG0AYQBpAG4ALgBHAGUAdABBAHMAcwBlAG0AYgBsAGkAZQBzACgAKQAgAHwARgBvAHIARQBhAGMAaAAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAARwBlAHQATgBhAG0AZQAgAHwAUwBvAHIAdAAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAATgBhAG0AZQA=
```

Comment: Nice, though probably worth running the fresh instance with `-noprofile` to eliminate side effects from `$PROFILE`.